# Trigger Reiterating over list

Tags: apex, trigger, order-of-execution

the below code should only go over the three entries int the EnttoUpdate list and then stop however it seems to be going over them multiple times and somehow assigning the wrong id

giving the error "Duplicate id In list 5504E000000DipYQAU

```
trigger EntilementUpdateEx on Contract (After Update) {


    List<Entitlement> EnttoUpdate = [Select ID From Entitlement Where contract__C in :Trigger.new];
    List<Contract> ContractsUpd = [Select ID, plantype__C, Productrange__C, StartDate, Enddate FROM Contract Where id in :trigger.new];
    List<Entitlement> EntUpdatelist = new List<Entitlement>();

    ID Missing  = 'a5v4E0000008cweQAA';
    ID Standard = '552580000004u8PAAQ';
    String MissingString = 'Missing';

    date Startdatedefault = date.newInstance(2010, 01, 01);

    System.debug(ContractsUpd);
    System.debug(EnttoUpdate);

    Map<String, Productrouting__C> EntitlementProductRangeID = new Map<String, Productrouting__C>(); 

    Map<String, slaprocess> EntitlementSlaProcess = new Map<String, slaprocess>(); 

    //Populate Maps

    //Map with Routing names and objects for retreivl later

   for(Productrouting__C objPR : [Select p.Name,p.id From Productrouting__C p] )

   EntitlementProductRangeID.put(objPR.name, objPR);

   System.debug(EntitlementProductRangeID);

    //Map with SLA names and objects for retreivl later

   for(slaprocess objPR : [Select p.Name,p.id From slaprocess p] )

   EntitlementSlaProcess.put(objPR.name, objPR);

   System.debug(EntitlementSlaProcess);    

    IF(Trigger.isupdate){

        If(EnttoUpdate.size() > 0){

             For(Entitlement Entupdate : EnttoUpdate){

                 for (integer i = 0; i < EnttoUpdate.size(); i++){


                     IF(EntitlementProductRangeID.containsKey(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C)){Entupdate.Name = ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C + ' ' + ContractsUpd[i].plantype__C;} Else {Entupdate.Name = MissingString + ' ' + ContractsUpd[i].plantype__C;}
                     IF(EntitlementSlaProcess.containsKey(ContractsUpd[i].plantype__C)){Entupdate.slaprocessid = EntitlementSlaProcess.get(ContractsUpd[i].plantype__C).id;} Else{Entupdate.slaprocessid = Standard;}     
                     IF(EntitlementProductRangeID.containsKey(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C)){Entupdate.ProductRouting__c = EntitlementProductRangeID.get(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C).id;} Else{Entupdate.ProductRouting__c = Missing;}
                     IF(EntitlementProductRangeID.containsKey(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C)){Entupdate.AssociatedProductRange__c = EntitlementProductRangeID.get(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C).name;} Else{Entupdate.AssociatedProductRange__c = MissingString;}
                     IF(ContractsUpd[i].StartDate == null){Entupdate.StartDate = Startdatedefault;} Else{Entupdate.StartDate = ContractsUpd[i].StartDate;}
                     Entupdate.EndDate = ContractsUpd[i].EndDate;

                     EntUpdatelist.add(Entupdate);


                     System.debug(EntUpdatelist);
                     System.debug(i);
        }
      }
    }

        //Else{

           // For(Contract Conupdate : ContractsUpd){

            //   integer i = 0;

            //     While (I < ContractsUpd.size()){

            //     entitlement ent = new entitlement();

            //     ent.ProductRouting__c = EntitlementProductRangeID.get(Conupdate.Productrange__C).id;

             //    EntUpdatelist.add(Entupdate);

            //   i++;
        //}    

    }

    Update EntUpdatelist;





}
```

Debug Log

[image]

Comment: Never, ever hardcode Ids.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I know its temporary to facilitate a test

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid duplicates by using a map.

Instead of:

```
List<MyObject__c> records = new List<MyObject__c>();
records.add(someRecord);
update records;
```

Use:

```
Map<Id, MyObject__c> records = new Map<Id, MyObject__c>();
records.put(someRecord.Id, someRecord);
update records.values();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, all this does is update all the records to the same values as the first in the list it doesnt help with the fact that only the first record is  being picked from the list and that the i++ is going 0,1,2,0,1,2 and trying to update only the first record

Answer (score 0):

Too many loops

fix

```
  integer i = 0;                 
        For(Entitlement Entupdate : EnttoUpdate){






                 IF(EntitlementProductRangeID.containsKey(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C)){Entupdate.Name = ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C + ' ' + ContractsUpd[i].plantype__C;} Else {Entupdate.Name = MissingString + ' ' + ContractsUpd[i].plantype__C;}
                 IF(EntitlementSlaProcess.containsKey(ContractsUpd[i].plantype__C)){Entupdate.slaprocessid = EntitlementSlaProcess.get(ContractsUpd[i].plantype__C).id;} Else{Entupdate.slaprocessid = Standard;}     
                 IF(EntitlementProductRangeID.containsKey(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C)){Entupdate.ProductRouting__c = EntitlementProductRangeID.get(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C).id;} Else{Entupdate.ProductRouting__c = Missing;}
                 IF(EntitlementProductRangeID.containsKey(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C)){Entupdate.AssociatedProductRange__c = EntitlementProductRangeID.get(ContractsUpd[i].Productrange__C).name;} Else{Entupdate.AssociatedProductRange__c = MissingString;}
                 IF(ContractsUpd[i].StartDate == null){Entupdate.StartDate = Startdatedefault;} Else{Entupdate.StartDate = ContractsUpd[i].StartDate;}
                 Entupdate.EndDate = ContractsUpd[i].EndDate;

                 EntUpdatelist.put(Entupdate.Id,Entupdate);

                 i++;
```